# PHP - Is $_GET still functional with spaces in the URL?

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I've got this simple question... If you've got spaces in the URL `$_GET`, lets say 
`"page=about us"`, and if you then use this code `IF($_GET['page']=='about us')`. Would that work? Or do you have to use `IF($_GET['page']=='about%20us')?`

Thanks for your time!

Comment: have you tried it yourself or you want us to try ?

Comment: yes, you should have tried it yourself.

Comment: I have not tried it myself, because I'm not currently able to...

Comment: Why are you not currently able to? If you don't have access to a PHP development/testing environment, what is your need for an answer?

Comment: I am able to try it on my second PC. But I'm not at home and still I was thinking of a way of completing a script and then this question popped up in my head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your browser converts the literal space in URLs into a `+` sign - before sending a HTTP request. When PHP sees that very `+` sign, it will become a space again for `$_GET`.

So, yes, it will work when comparing it against `== "about us"`. Don't compare against the `%20`. (That's a valid, but unlikely encoding in URLs anyway.)

*Sidenode*. It's best not to rely on browser magic. When outputting the link, embed the `+` in place of spaces yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [url_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).